# Response time for a UIButton for an iPad application

Tags: iphone, time, uibutton, response, ipad

i have a simple UIButton that, once clicked, plays a 1 second sound. i want to be able to click that button really fast and produce that sound as many times as i humanly can.

i currently have this up and running by including the  and maybe that is where the culprit is... also, i am digging into apple's references and cannot find the info for how quick is a UIButton to respond to each event and how, if at all, i can control and manipulate this value.

should i switch to a different audio framework like the "audio toolbox" or is there a way for me to speed things up, or perhaps instruct a button to accept a 2nd and 3rd press while the action of the first press is still underway.

cheers!

~nir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method to play the sound separate from the button handler method.  Let's say you call it `playSound`.  In your button handler, execute that method in the background with:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(playSound) withObject:nil];
```

That does incur additional overhead to spawn off a thread before it can play the sound.  If you want to speed it up a bit more, create a pool of worker threads and use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playSound) 
             onThread:nextThread 
           withObject:nil 
        waitUntilDone:NO];
```

To create the pool of worker threads:

```
-(void)stillWorking {
    NSLog(@"Still working!");
}

-(void)workerThreadMain {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSTimer *threadTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 
                                                            target:self 
                                                          selector:@selector(stillWorking) 
                                                          userInfo:nil 
                                                           repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:threadTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    [pool drain];
}

-(NSArray*)createWorkerThreads { 
    NSMutableArray *threadArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10]autorelease];
    NSThread *workerThread;

    for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
        workerThread = [[NSThread alloc]initWithTarget:self 
                                              selector:@selector(workerThreadMain) 
                                                object:nil];
        [workerThread start];
        [threadArray addObject:workerThread];
    }
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:threadArray];
}
```

(This code is untested and may require some debugging, but it should get you going in the right direction.)

Comment: thanx john.

i've tried the first solution you had offered and the interval between sounds is actually slower than before. to test things out i attached a 5 seconds sound to the button and tried clicking it within 2-3 seconds interval, expecting the sounds to overlap - well - they do not. the button is still waiting for the first sound to finish even though i had separated the control from the play method call.

before i go head and dig into the array of working threads - what are your thoughts about this outcome? why won't the button allow more than one thread to fork?

thanks again!

Comment: If it is not playing overlapping sounds, I would suspect the call to play the sound is waiting for prior calls to complete first.